# jq add list to object list until condition

Tags: json, bash, dictionary, jq

**Background**

I have an object with each value being a nested list of only strings. For each string value within the nested list, look up the string value within the object and add all of its values into the current value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

in=$(jq -n '{
  "bar": [["re", "de"]],
  "do": [["bar","baz"]],
  "baz": [["re"]],
  "re": [["zoo"]]
}')

echo "expected:"
jq -n '{
  "bar": [["re", "de"], ["zoo"]],
  "do": [["bar","baz"], ["re", "de"], ["re"], ["zoo"]],
  "baz": [["re"], ["zoo"]],
  "re": [["zoo"]]
}'

echo "actual:"
echo ${in} | jq '. as $origin 
  | map_values( . + 
    until(
      length == 0;
      (. | flatten | map($origin[.]) | map(select( . != [[]] )) | add ) 
    )
  )'
```

**Problem:**

The output is the exact same as the input `$in`. If the `until()` function is removed from the statement, then the output correctly outputs one iteration. Although I want to recursively lookup the output strings within the object and add the lookup value until the lookup value is empty or non-existing.

For example, the key `do` has a value of `[["bar","baz"]]`. If we iterate through the values of `do` we come across `baz`. The value of `baz` within the object is `[["re"]]`. Add `baz`'s value `["re"]` to `do` so that `do` equals: `[["bar","baz"], ["re"]]`. Since `re` IS a key within the object, add the value of `["re"]` which is `["zoo"]`. Since `["zoo"]` is NOT a key within the object finish `baz` and continue to the next key within the object.

Answer (score 0):

The following solves the problem as originally stated, but the "expected" output as shown does not quite match the stated problem.

```
echo ${in} | jq -c '
  . as $dict
  | map_values(reduce (..|strings) as $v (.;
                       . + $dict[$v] ))
'
```

produces (after some manual reformatting for clarity):

```
{"bar":[["re","de"],["zoo"]],
  "do":[["bar","baz"],["re","de"],["re"]],
 "baz":[["re"],["zoo"]],"re":[["zoo"]]}
```

If some kind of recursive lookup is needed, then please reformulate the problem statement, being sure to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: thanks @peak for your answer. A recursive lookup is needed, I'll update my problem statement.